# ELB HAproxy and cookies

Tags: cookies, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

I'm using ELB in front of HA-Proxy. Stickiness is disable on ELB and I have this configuration in HA-Proxy:

```
backend endpoint
    balance leastconn
    cookie  VALUE insert nocache maxidle 30
```

I'm using curl to query and I noticed that if I query directly HA-Proxy I get a cookie for each query. However with ELB, I would get a cookie at the first query but not with the next ones, I have to wait few minutes before it give me a cookie.

Any idea why?

HA-Proxy version 1.4.18 2011/09/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I needed to ask HA-Proxy to close the connection as soon as possible using *option http-server-close* or *option forceclose*.

More information about ELB keepalive can be found here

> ELB's HTTP listeners present an HTTP 1.1 endpoint to clients, which means that:
>
> - HTTP Keepalive will be enabled by default for an HTTP 1.1 client
> - HTTP Keepalive will be disabled by default for an HTTP 1.0 client
> - In either case, the client can explicitly turn keepalive on or off by including the "Connection: keep-alive" or "Connection: close" headers, respectively, in the request.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=200999&#200999